# Message EventListener returns cf-tick

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

My question is simple,

I have this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, false);
function messageHandler(event)
{
        if(event.data) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = event.data;
        }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="test"></span>
</body>
```

which returns me this,when it shouldn't return me anything

```
cf-tick
```

Why is this? and How can i stop this?

A live example is this: [Test Page](http://youify.in/ieee/trying.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have cloudflare js

```
http://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok8v=221574e73d/cloudflare.min.js
```

loaded in your page which posts the message `cf-tick`. You can see the file posting a message if you search for the following code in the file :

```
a.postMessage("cf-tick","*")
```

If you remove the loading of **CloudFlare** script, no message will be posted to the webpage.
If you don't want the `cf-tick` to get caught in the event listener, you can check if the message is not `cf-tick` :

```
window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, false);
function messageHandler(event){
 if(event.data) {
  if(event.data!="cf-tick")
   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = event.data;
 }
}
```